# LDAP-authentication and local roles don't work

Tags: grails, ldap, roles, spring-security

authentication via LDAP works like a charm, however, when I assign a role to a user and secure a page in the requestmap (like `/books/show/**` and `ROLE_USER`) this only works for local-only users, not for users authenticated via LDAP. (`IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` works, though)

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head, meet Wall.

Just add `ldapRetrieveDatabaseRoles = true` to your SecurityConfig.groovy – that's all.